# Why is this invalid xml format?

Tags: xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<Pattern id="1" >

    <condition>

    </condition>

</Pattern>

<Pattern id="2">


    <condition>

    </condition>

</Pattern>
```

In Google Chrome, it says:

```
error on line 12 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
```

Does it mean that in XML file, it doesn't allow two tags with the same name, i.e. 'Pattern' here? If that's true and I want to represent multiple patterns in a xml file, how to do that?

Comment: You can have only one root element, you have two. Put the `<Pattern>` tags in a new element like `<Patterns>`.

Comment: (1) Your XML is not well-formed because it is missing a root element. (2) XML cannot be even considered valid or not without XML Schema (XSD). It takes two to tango, i.e. XMl/XSD.

Comment: Can I allow multiple "Pattern" at the same level in XML? If not, is that possible by using user defined XSD file or other means?

Comment: @marlon, you can have multiple `<Pattern>` elements under the root.

Comment: @Progman I can add <Patterns> tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you need a root element. You can have multiple Patterns at the same level -- so long as it is not the root level. For example, this would be legitimate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Patterns>
<Pattern id="1" >
    <condition>
    </condition>
</Pattern>

<Pattern id="2">
    <condition>
    </condition>

</Pattern>
</Patterns>
```

Comment: Usually, when do I need to define my own XSD file when working with XML file? In my above use cases, I don't need to provide my own XSD. Right?

Comment: You don’t __have__ to have XSD - if not then there’s no way of confirming the content is anything but syntactically correct- , but if you do have XSD then it enables additional validation of the XML.

Comment: Since this is your own structure, there's no need to bother with an XSD -- unless you can't really trust the method you're using to generate the data (and if that's the case, you're better off making sure the data is good in first place rather than defining an XSD that will just make your processes choke)

Comment: @KyleBanerjee What do you mean by 'your own structure'? It's always going to be the XML file producer to decide whether a XSD file is necessary or not. Isn't that right? I had thought XSD is required when the 'default' xml schema is not sufficient for data representation, and this default schema is always provided by xml parser and no user action is required.

Comment: "Your own structure" = "You made up the XML to fit the purposes at hand." No need to validate your own stuff or data you can trust. Validation is for when you can't trust what you're getting and it's on whoever provided it to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, your input is a well-formed general parsed entity (sometimes called a well-formed fragment) but it is not a well-formed document.

Some XML parsers offer an option to accept a well-formed fragment as input (for example Microsoft's System.Xml parser) but most don't, and it is never the default.